# Android force start and end to be constant

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to set a span to have a constant `start` and `end` positions, e.g. I don't want the span to grow anymore after the `start` and `end` position were given to it (via `editable.setSpan`).

For example:
My edit text:

Hi **bob**
(span at: [3, 6])

Now if I type in lets say: "a" it will continue to "streach" the span:

Hi **boba**

I want the span's start and end positions to be static, therefore the span should not grow after it has been set with the start
and end positions - only [3,6] should be in the span, not [6,7].

Note: I've tried `EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE`  but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: see SpanWatcher interface and in particular onSpanChanged method

Comment: @pskink, I tried implementing a class with the text watcher but it didn't seem to be the right direction, how can I force the span not to change?

Comment: you can't,  but using spanwatcher you can detect if it changed and then to set it to the original position

Comment: @pskink, it sounds super hacky and wasteful. I'll keep looking for something, maybe I'll open a bounty.

Comment: it's not hacky,  this is how spans work...